# How to run gremlin scripts on a remote gremlin-server for titan/hbase?

Tags: gremlin, titan, tinkerpop, gremlin-server

I am using titan/hbase to store my data and Titan and Hbase resides in a remote server machine. I started Gremlin server with `bin/titan.sh start`. After that I ran following commands on server machine, which worked fine:

```
bin/gremlin.sh 

         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----
plugin activated: aurelius.titan
plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/titan-1.0.0-hadoop1/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/titan-1.0.0-hadoop1/lib/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
18:32:20 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.HadoopGraph  - HADOOP_GREMLIN_LIBS is set to: /usr/local/titan-1.0.0-hadoop1/lib
plugin activated: tinkerpop.hadoop
plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph
gremlin> g = TitanFactory.open("conf/titan-hbase.properties")
==>standardtitangraph[hbase:[192.168.1.65]]
gremlin> gr = g.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[standardtitangraph[hbase:[192.168.1.65]], standard]
gremlin> gr.V().count()
18:33:37 WARN  com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.transaction.StandardTitanTx  - Query requires iterating over all vertices [()]. For better performance, use indexes
==>41
```

Now to check remote connection, I just ran `gremlin.sh` from the client machine and ran

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml 
g=TitanFactory.open("conf/titan-hbase.properties")
```

I get following:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getDeployment(HBaseStoreManager.java:351)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getFeatures(HBaseStoreManager.java:389)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.<init>(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.java:1321)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:94)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory.open(TitanFactory.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:78)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GraphManager.lambda$new$27(GraphManager.java:50)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntrySet.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:663)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GraphManager.<init>(GraphManager.java:48)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:94)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:88)
    at pluradj.titan.tinkerpop3.example.ServiceTest.startServer(ServiceTest.java:37)
    at pluradj.titan.tinkerpop3.example.ServiceTest.setUp(ServiceTest.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.ensureTableExists(HBaseStoreManager.java:759)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getLocalKeyPartition(HBaseStoreManager.java:556)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.getDeployment(HBaseStoreManager.java:347)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=35, exceptions:

    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:129)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:169)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:164)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:736)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.MetaReader.fullScan(MetaReader.java:539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.catalog.MetaReader.tableExists(MetaReader.java:310)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:279)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:293)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseAdmin0_98.tableExists(HBaseAdmin0_98.java:93)
    at com.thinkaurelius.titan.diskstorage.hbase.HBaseStoreManager.ensureTableExists(HBaseStoreManager.java:753)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$Connection.setupConnection(RpcClient.java:578)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(RpcClient.java:866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.getConnection(RpcClient.java:1536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.call(RpcClient.java:1435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1654)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1712)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:29900)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:157)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:114)
    ... 57 more
```

My titan-hbase.properties is:

```
storage.backend=hbase
storage.hostname=192.168.1.65
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
gremlin.graph=com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TtanFactory
storage.hbase.tablename = titan
```

and remote.yaml is :

```
hosts: [192.168.1.65]
port: 8182
serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV1d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}
```

What is going wrong here ? How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is configure Gremlin Server with the Titan-HBase properties. You should not use `titan.sh` at all for this scenario because it automatically starts a Cassandra and Elasticsearch node, so make sure to shut that down with `bin/titan.sh stop` before continuing.

1. Place your `titan-hbase.properties` under `conf/gremlin-server/`. What you posted above looked fine, except the last property name should be `storage.hbase.table`.
2. Update the `gremlin-server.yaml` under `conf/gremlin-server/` with your Titan-HBase configuration (the default configuration uses Cassandra + Elasticsearch). Also, keep in mind if you want to connect to the Gremlin Server from a different machine, you'll need to update the `host` to the server's IP address `192.168.1.65`.

   > graphs: { graph: conf/gremlin-server/titan-hbase.properties }
3. Start the Gremlin Server with `bin/gremlin-server.sh`. Watch the logs for errors on startup. If successful, you should see an INFO message saying `graph` and `g` were configured and bound. `g` is defined in `scripts/empty-sample.groovy` script which is loaded via `conf/gremlin-server.yaml`.

   > `8456 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Graph [graph] was successfully configured via [conf/gremlin-server/titan-hbase.properties].
   >   9349 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor  - A GraphTraversalSource is now bound to [g] with graphtraversalsource[standardtitangraph[hbase:[127.0.0.1]], standard]`
4. Start the Gremlin Console, and create a remote connection using `conf/remote.yaml` to the Gremlin Server. Since `graph` and `g` are already bound through the server configuration, you don't need to initialize them in the console. Make sure you send the commands to the remote server by using `:>` at the beginning of your query.

Here's an example Gremlin Console session:

```
gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml
==>Connected - localhost/127.0.0.1:8182
gremlin> :> g.V().count()
==>12
```

Refer to the [Apache TinkerPop documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#connecting-via-console) for connecting to the Gremlin Server from the Gremlin Console.